# How do create a page with two .cs files?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

Here is a easy one for u:
I want to create a page with two .cs files:

```
MainPage.cs
MainPage.xaml
MainPage.xaml.cs
```

how do I do it?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Partial Classes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Partial class definitions allow you to spread classes among several files.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can create two files like this.

```
//MainPage.cs
public partial class MainPage
{
    private void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
//MainPage2.aspx
public partial class MainPage
{
    public void GetSomething()
    {
        DoSomething();
    }
}
```